# codeigniter - trying to get property of non-object error because i was trying to get the value of the user's input

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting the error trying to get property of non-object.

this is my code:

```
<?php include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../admin-panel.php';
  $arr=[];
  foreach ($data as $value) 
  {
    $arr = $value;
  }
?>
```

and then in my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Recipient's Mobile Number</label> 
  <input type="text" name="number" class ="form-control" maxlength="11" value="<?= $arr->contact_num ?>">
</div>
```

the error occurs in

```
value="<?= $arr->contact_num ?>"
```

Comment: `arr` is a array, you need to take object from that array and then get `contact_num`, should be like `arr[0]->contact_num`, you need to also check from which position of array you need your object.

Comment: $arr is an array not an object change the variable according to array $arr

Comment: that's some weird lookin CI code...

Answer (score 0):

You are not using array syntax correctly. $arr is an array so you need to use it like this $arr[] = $value;

Answer (score 0):

update your codes by following

**PHP**

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../admin-panel.php';
$arr=[];
foreach ($data as $value){
    $arr[] = $value;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<?php if($arr){ foreach($arr as $row){ ?>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Recipient's Mobile Number</label> 
  <input type="text" name="number" class ="form-control" maxlength="11" value="<?= $row->contact_num; ?>">
</div>
<?php }} ?>
```